# How can I set up a mailer with data from 2 queries

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to make an automatic mailer for my Laravel app.

I use 1 query to retrieve the user with his email address. Then I want to use a second query to retrieve data that is relevant to the user in another table.
Finally, an email must be created with this information and sent automatically.

Can this build via blade or in the controller?

Comment: Actually it just sounds like you're missing some fundamentals and you need to go brush up. I recommend Laracasts as a good starting point. You'll probably want to set up Events and Listeners so you can queue your sending of emails as background tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do what you indicate. Example:

**Controller**

```
...
$user = User::firstOrFail($id);
$order =  Order::firstOrFail($order_id);

Mail::send(new Notification($user, $order));
...
```

**Mailable**

```
class Notification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $order;

    public function __construct(User $user, Order $order)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('example@example.com', 'Example'))
            ->subject('Order processed')
            ->view('emails.notification')
            ->with([
                'name' => $this->user->name,
                'code' => $this->order->code,
                'amount' => $this->order->amount,
            ]);
    }
}
```

**View Blade**

```
Hi, {{$name}},

Your order {{$code}} has already been processed for an amount of {{$amount}}.

A cordial greeting.
```

Remember to configure your .env file with the values of your mail server.

Example for gmail

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

[More information on creating mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#generating-mailables)

Please accept it as the correct answer, if it has been helpful. Thank you.

A cordial greeting.